# Is the Crystal Reports WPF viewer control included with Crystal Reports 2011?

Tags: crystal-reports

The WPF viewer was released with "Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010". I have installed Crystal Reports 2011 and as far as I can tell, none of the viewers are included. Am I missing something?

Comment: In the future, all answers to this question will we wrong.

Comment: Good point. I reworded the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Crystal Reports viewers were split off from the main product into the "Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010" product and are not part of Crystal Reports 2011. It may be that in a future non-"for Visual Studio" Crystal Reports release, a new version of the viewers will be released. As of 04 OCT 2011, the newest version of the viewers is found in "Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010."